# Proving $e^{-\frac{x^2}{\alpha}} < \frac{\alpha}{x^2 + \alpha}$ for all $x \neq 0$.

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponential-function

I have been trying to prove the following inequality for all $x \neq 0$, with little success. Here, $\alpha \in (0, \infty)$; i.e., $\alpha$ is always some positive real number.

$$e^{-\frac{x^2}{\alpha}} < \frac{\alpha}{x^2 + \alpha}$$

In truth, it is easy to transform the inequality to pretty inteligible expressions. One of my attempts, for example, lead to $f(x) (1+\frac{x^2}{\alpha}) < 1$, with $f(x) = e^{-\frac{x^2}{\alpha}}$. The problem is we know $f(x) = e^{-\frac{x^2}{\alpha}} \in (0, 1]$, so the expression shown before is not as trivial as it seems.

How could I go about proving this?

Comment: How about $x^2 = \alpha$?

Comment: Are you sure you have the inequality the right way around?

Comment: Jesus... Thank you @messenger, that was a typo.

Comment: We can start with $e^t>t+1$ for $t\neq0$. Letting $t=x^2/\alpha$ gives $e^{x^2/\alpha}>\frac{x^2}\alpha+1=\frac{x^2+\alpha}\alpha$, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: @Feng that was clear as day. Would you put that in an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can start with $e^t>t+1$ for $t\neq 0$. Letting $t=x^2/\alpha$ gives that
$$e^{\frac{x^2}\alpha}>\frac{x^2}\alpha+1=\frac{x^2+\alpha}\alpha,\qquad x\neq0,\alpha>0.$$
which is equivalent to
$$e^{-\frac{x^2}\alpha}<\frac{\alpha}{x^2+\alpha},\qquad x\neq0,\alpha>0.$$

Answer (score 1):

The given inequality is equivalent to $\alpha e^{x^{2}/\alpha} <x^{2}+\alpha$.

$e^{t/\alpha} -(t+\alpha)/\alpha$ is increasing in $[0,\infty)$ because its derivative is positive. This function vansihes at $0$ so $e^{t/\alpha} > (t+\alpha)/\alpha$ for all $t >$. Put $t=x^{2}$ to finish.

Comment: Why do your write $t+\alpha$/$\alpha$ when it is $\frac{t}{t+\alpha}$?

Comment: @lafinur Is the answer clear now?